# html protect th cells in a table

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I am trying to disabled th cells in a html table to avoid any clicking problem but it seems that disabled property is not available for this.

`focusout()` on click doesn't work very well so I ask for help to find a better solution.

Comment: Clicking a th doesn't do anything by default. What specific action are you trying to prevent? Can you post an example of your code?

Comment: What do you mean? Prevent copy/paste? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent selecting the text, use CSS property `user-select: none`.

```css
.noselect{
-webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; 
}
th{
 border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th class="noselect">You can't select this</th>
<th>You can select this</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's exactly what I was looking for. Now I have the solution